# FBLoginKIt integration issue +[FBSDKInternalUtility areAllPermissionsReadPermissions:]: unrecognized selector

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

App crashes when tapping on FBSDKLoginButton:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBSDKLoginButton *fbLoginButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [_fbLoginButton setReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
    [_fbLoginButton setDelegate:self];
}
```

Nothing more than this but when tap on the button app crashes with below messages.

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[FBSDKInternalUtility areAllPermissionsReadPermissions:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100296a00'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this error when I was using two different Facebook frameworks (specifically `FBSDKCoreKit.framework` and `FBSDKLoginKit.framework`) that were from different release packages.

Make sure that all of your Facebook frameworks are from the same release package.  You can see a list of stable releases [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads).

This issue can also come up when using a service like Gigya that intergrates with Facebook's SDK.  If you're using Gigya, make sure you're using the version of the Facebook SDK that they recommend rather than the latest version.

Comment: Thank you! I updated to the most recent FBSDK cocoapod versions and it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There are instructions on how to configure your Gigya iOS project with Facebook. Please have a look at: http://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/iOS#iOS-ConfiguringNativeLogin

Alternatively you can always download our demo project which shows integration with Facebook. This is on the link I have provided you with.